# How does geofencing work?

Tags: gis-principle, geofencing

How does geofencing work? I am aware that it creates a sort of polygonal bubble which can execute a certain action when you pass through it, but how does it actually do that without just constantly polling GPS? [This site](http://devblog.highlig.ht/post/78783186365/how-we-improved-highlights-battery-life-5x) states that they improved battery usage using geofences instead of just polling GPS, so it must be different

Comment: There is some information on Esri's version of this (GeoTriggers) at https://developers.arcgis.com/geotrigger-service/guide/faq/#how-does-the-geotrigger-service-work - I'd suggest the answer to _what's it doing in the background?_ would be _that's a trade secret_

Comment: Each app is going to implement this a bit differently, which makes this difficult to answer as-is.

Comment: Can I suggest it only pushes when outside (or inside) so the saving is on the push not the collection frequency or detail. Likely only stores when triggered as well so this is a saving. This is speculation as I have no inside knowledge. Yo may be able to use a trigger such as cellular tower (left the default) or even wireless network (left the building) in addition to GPS on mobile enabled devices.